# Proof that $\overline{B}_1(0)$ is not compact in $(C[0,1],||\cdot||_{\infty})$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, compactness

I am asked to prove the following statement

> The set $\overline{B}_1(0)$ is not compact in
>   $(C[0,1],||\cdot||_{\infty})$ and $\overline{B}_1(0)=\{f\in
>  C[0,1]:||f||_{\infty}\leq1\}$

My attempt was the following:

Find a function $h_k(f)$ where $f(x) = ?$ s.t.: 
$$||h_k(f)-h_m(f)||_{\infty} = const.$$

I am trying to use the definition that a set is called compact if every sequence does have a convergent subsequence.

---

*The idea behind the constant value came to me when solving the exact same question but for $(\mathbb{R},||\cdot||_{\infty})$, where I found the function 
$$
    f_k(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if } x= \frac{1}{k}\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
when applying the cauchy-criteria one can define (for example) $\epsilon := \frac{1}{2}$ and see that $||f_k-f_m||_{\infty} = 1 > \epsilon \implies \overline{B}_1(0)$ not compact in $(\mathbb{R},||\cdot||_{\infty})$*

---

Coming now back to my actual question: Could anyone give me a push in the right direction, what the best way would be to define my $h_k(f)$ or maybe tell me if I am on the complete wrong track with my idea?

It's been some weeks since we introduced the $C[0,1]$ but I am still struggling a bit to work with it thus having a hard time solving this particular excercise.

Thank you in advance :)

P.S.: Since I don't know if $C[0,1]$ is a general used definition: We defined $C[0,1]$ as the space of continuous functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define a function $f_n\in C\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$ such that:

- $x\notin\left[\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right]\implies f_n(x)=0$;
- $(\forall x\in[0,1]):-1\leqslant f_n(x)\leqslant 1$;
- $f_n(x_n)=1$ for some $x_n\in\left[\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right]$.

It follows from this that $m\neq n\implies\|f_m-f_n\|_\infty=1$. Therefore, $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has no Cauchy subsequence, and therefore no convergent subsequence.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems like a good idea for a function, though I am not able to see how I can prove, that this is a continuous sequence of functions. $\epsilon - \delta$ doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Note that I did not define the functions. I told you do it yourself. Do you need some help?

Comment: I am thinking of something like $f_n(x_n)=\frac{1}{((x+n)^2+1)^{10}}$. Does this make sense? Obviously this just makes sense if my assumption is correct that $C[0,1]$ doesn't contain complex functions.

Comment: @MLK There is no way such a function satisfies the three conditions that I described.

Comment: Sadly this is one of the only functions I know that only possess one peak and satisfies $-1 \leq f_n(x) \leq 1$ at least in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Define$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x\notin\left[\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right]\\2(n^2+n)\left(x-\frac1{n+1}\right)&\text{ if }x\in\left[\frac1{n+1},\frac12\left(\frac1{n+1}+\frac1n\right)\right]\\2(n^2+n)\left(x-\frac1n\right)&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: I must admit that I would not have come up with such a function. I don't want to bother you with asking what the thinking behind this function was but rather just thank you. Thank you for taking your time.

Comment: Actually, whenI wrote $x-\frac1n$, I should have written $\frac1n-x$.